# distributing a value into 3 input tag

Tags: javascript, php

I have software design that to distribute a value into 3 input tags.

```
<?php
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_BOTH)){

       $qtyAvailable = $row['QTY_REQUIRED'] - $row['QTY_CNCED'];   

       echo '<input class="form-control" id="test1" name="quantityToCutCnc" type="number" min="0" max='.$qtyAvailable.' placeholder="CNC">';

       echo '<input class="form-control" id="test2" name="quantityToCutScator" type="number" min="0" max='.$qtyAvailable.' placeholder="Scator">';

       echo '<input class="form-control" id="test3" name="quantityToCutManual" type="number" min="0" max='.$qtyAvailable.' placeholder="Manual">';
       echo '<br/>';
       echo '<strong>Total : </strong><div id="spent"></div>';

       echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>';
       echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.js"></script>';

       echo '<script src="componentRequestJS/qtyDistribution.js"></script>';
}
?>
```

So i need to distribute `$qtyAvailable` into `quantityToCutCnc, quantityToCutScator, and quantityToCutManual`. So the sum of those 3 cannot exceed `$qtyAvailable`. I am assuming that we need to use jQuery with that.

Comment: What does `$qtyAvailable` contain? And "distribute" how? Please clarify.

Comment: no, you don't "need" jquery. it's just a javascript library. but you DO need javascript for this, unless you want to subject your users to a full-blown form submission/page rebuild so you can do the calculations on the server.

Comment: @AmalMurali So quantity available is retrieved from the database and some values will be assigned in this variable. Distributing means that we are going to have a number selector on those 3 inputs. but the sums of that number cant exceed $qtyAvailable. its setting the limit of max="". So when the $qtyAvailable is 10 then if the 2 inputs are 0 then the 1 input can reach up to 10. if we reduce the first input value then we can increase the other 2 inputs

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How do you want to split them if the quantity available is 15 for example?

Comment: @AmalMurali if the qty is 15, then if the first input is 15 then the other 2 inputs cant be inputted. then if the first input is 10 then there are 5 available to be distributed into the other 2 inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a good starting point, I think:

http://jsfiddle.net/X8RFe/2/

```
// echo from php
var available = 20;

jQuery('.form_control').on('change',function(event) {


    setTimeout(function() {
        var used = 0;
        jQuery('.form_control').each(function() {
            used += (parseInt(jQuery(this).val(),10) || 0);
        });

        if (used > available) {

            var current = parseInt(jQuery(event.target).val(),10);

             jQuery(event.target).val(current-(used-available));    
        }
    },1);

});
```

You'll probably want to test and tweak it a bit further, as I only tested it for a few seconds.

Comment: When i was testing this, the upper limit is not properly set. so the total qty is 20 and when i set the 1st and 2nd input, i can still increase the 3rd input. 3rd input should be not editable when the other 2 reached 20. isnt it?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. It may help to take a look at the fiddle to see how it's working.

Comment: one last question , how do i pass the $row['QTY_REQUIRED'] to the javascript ?

Comment: hey dg988 its an amazing answer, but you use class="form control". how do i do if i separate the 3 inputs with different name ?

Comment: You can target them however you like. You can use 3 separate `id`'s but I'd recommend sticking with a class. Perhaps `.cut_distribution`. You should `echo` the necessary variables right into a `<script>` tag.

Comment: the thing is, i need to record each of the input value into the database. is that possible with a class ?

Comment: How would changing a jQuery selector and adding  class name to the `input`s hinder, or even affect that? Nothing should change with how you are submitting the form.